# Why are there so many Shark based monster movies these days?

Tags: film-industry

Other than Jaws and maybe that [movie with LL Cool J and Samuel L Jackson](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0149261/), I can't really think of many shark monster/horror movies. But suddenly it seems to me that there is a new shark monster movie every few weeks.

Is there actually such a sudden trend in releasing so many shark-themed movies? If yes, what was the pivotal moment/event which triggered the production of all of these masterpieces? Or is it just a rising attention those movies seem to get in the media for some reason?

Comment: Why **not**??? I mean... it's ***sharks***.

Comment: I think the premise of your question is wrong. Shark movies have always been around: http://www.imdb.com/list/ls002583733/

Comment: @DA. Then that might be the base for an answer, if fleshed-out properly.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson the answer would be "the question is incorrect" so I'd suggest the OP edit the question to be more specific or we consider closing it.

Comment: @DA. But it (the answer) would provide sufficient reference to show in which way the asker's perception was wrong. That seems like a valid answer. I tried to improve the question a bit in this regard.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson OK. I gave it a go!

Comment: because sharks are terrifying.

Comment: always up for more sharknado!!!

Answer (score 3):

> I can't really think of many shark monster/horror movies.

That's why the internet was invented. We no longer have to think. :)

A quick search finds that there's nothing particular 'new' about shark movies. They seem to have been consistently popular as subject matter (if not viewing manner) since the original JAWS. This is merely one list of many on IMDB. This one lists 53 different shark movies over the past 4 decades:

http://www.imdb.com/list/ls002583733/

Now, one could argue there are more movies post-2000 on average featuring sharks. I don't have a concrete answer to that, but I'd posit that it's not specific to sharks, but rather, we have a lot more monster movies in general post-2000 due to all the advancements in CGI availability to film makers at all budget ranges. JAWS was not an easy shark to make. Now a talented teenager can make their own with software and put it on YouTube.

Comment: **Shark Week** started getting more popular in the late 1990s.